# delayed_job_active_record - Undefined method `any?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

Attempting to send some stuff to the background with [delayed_job_active_record](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record), but how come I can't use `any?`? Works fine when things are not sent into the background.

```
undefined method `any?' for #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job:0x000000044b1348>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if @products.any? %>
  <div class="products">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= product.name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="products processing">

    <!-- Try again later -->

  </div>
<% end %>
```

**main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Delay fetching
    @products = Affiliate.delay.fetch
  end
end
```

**affiliate.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      affiliate = Affiliate.find_or_create_by(:name => product.name, :url => product.url)
      affiliate.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is @items & where did it come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because `@products` isn't an array any more - it's a reference to a job that will get executed at some time in the future

You need a rethink of how your setup works. For example your view could poll via Ajax to see if the job has been completed. If it has then fetch the results from the DB, since you seem to be saving the API results there.

Comment: That's not how delayed_job works - @products will never be anything but a job reference (and the return value of the method you delay is not kept anywhere either)

Comment: Yep I think I understand it now. Have a great weekend!